# Updating a bar chart with .update, .enter, and .exit?

Tags: d3.js

I have made a simple bar chart. I want to update the bars (on the fly) by toggling between different subsets of my data. From what I've seen, there appears to be two approaches:

1. Draw the chart, and on a button click (or whatever) remove the whole chart and redraw it.
2. Use different data selections to 'update', 'enter' and 'exit' the bars from the chart on a button click.

I'm attempting option 2. Here's my code:

```
// set dimensions
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 100};
var height = 600 -margin.top - margin.bottom;
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;

// set ranges
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([width, 0]);
var y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .05);

// define y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

// add svg container
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
.append("svg")
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load data
d3.json("data.json", function(data) {

  // format data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.enrols = +d.enrols;
  });

  // register click event
  d3.selectAll(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    render(this.id);
  });

  // initialise
  render("group-1");

  function render(selection) {

    // filter data
    var subset = data.filter(function(d) { return d.group === selection} );

    // scale range of data
    x.domain([0, d3.max(subset, function(d) { return d.enrols; })]);
    y.domain(subset.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));

    // update selection
    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(subset, function(d) { return d.month; });

    // add bars
    bars.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + y(d.month) + ")";
    });

    bars.append("rect")
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("width", function (d) {
      return width - x(d.enrols);
    });

    bars.append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return width - x(d.enrols) - 15;
    })
    .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.enrols;
    });

    bars.exit().remove();

    // add y axis
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  }

});
```

Problem is my old data never gets exited, the new bars are appended, but the old ones remain. I've read the theory of d3 selections, but I'm finding them hard to implement in practice.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/24ma13wg/pen/Rowqmo). Here is [data.json](http://codepen.io/24ma13wg/pen/vyYQbK.js).

Comment: `selectAll(".bars")` is wrong as there are no elements with the class `bars`, there are only elements with class `bar`. You're creating multiple axes. And you're also appending multiple bars to the same group `g` element. Look at the SVG being generated in your codepen.

Comment: You mean like this: http://codepen.io/24ma13wg/pen/jVOgRj? Doesn't seem to help?

Comment: Very good! You solved almost all the problems in your codepen. You're still adding a new axis to your chart every time the `render` function is called. You should fix that. In any case, I can now explain you d3's data joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bar chart only needs a very simple modification. Here's the missing puzzle piece:

When we use the `data()` function, D3 performs a [`join` operation](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) between the existing DOM elements and your data values. You store the result of this operation on the variable `bars`. We can call several methods on `bars`.

The method `exit()` returns elements that are going to be removed. If we have 3 bars on the DOM and we call the `data()` function with an array with just 2 data values, `exit()` will return the bar that will be removed.

Likewise, the method `enter()` returns elements that are going to be added. If we have 2 bars on the DOM and we call the `data()` function with an array with 3 data values, `enter()` will return the new bar that will be added.

Then what about the bars that are going to be updated? Well, they're what's stored in the `bars` variable!

Translating this to code is very simple:

This:

```
bars.enter()
  .append("g")
  ...
```

is turned into this:

```
var newBars = bars.enter()
  .append("g")
  ...
```

And then every time this appears:

```
bars.append(...)
```

is turned into this:

```
newBars.append(...)
```

Every time there is a new bar, we `append` something to the DOM.

Every time we need to update a bar, we `select` something from the DOM.

`bars` refer to the bars that are going to be updated. So we add this code to update existing bars:

```
bars.select('rect')
  .attr("width", function (d) {
    return width - x(d.enrols);
  });

bars.select('text')
  .attr("x", function (d) {
    return width - x(d.enrols) - 15;
  })
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.enrols;
  });
```

Comment: I follow your logic: `bars` holds the joined dom elements and data; store the new bars to be added in a variable, and there is no need to remove anything, but update with `selectAll`. All I'm getting though is the width of my bars increasing a bit on each toggle?? Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/24ma13wg/pen/jVOgRj

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. Where I wrote `selectAll`, it should read `select`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Btw, there are a few differences between data joins in D3 v3 and in D3 v4. If you're interested in understanding these differences, check out What [Makes Good Software Good](https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488#708a).

Answer (score 3):

It's very good that you have chosen the second option over the first: removing all elements and drawing the chart again is a very lazy way of coding.

However, in your case, as the length of the data doesn't change, you *don't need* an "enter", "update" and "exit" selections!

It's everything way easier if you move some non-changing parts outside your `render`function:

```
y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.month;
}));

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.month;
    }).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + y(d.month) + ")";
    });

var rects = bars.append("rect")
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return width - x(d.enrols);
    });

var texts = bars.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return width - x(d.enrols) - 15;
    })
    .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.enrols;
    });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

And keep inside it only what really changes:

- The domain of your x scale,
- The data bound to the groups,
- The transitions for the rectangles and texts.

It would be way smaller:

```
function render(selection) {

    // filter data
    var subset = data.filter(function(d) {
        return d.group === selection
    });

    // scale range of data
    x.domain([0, d3.max(subset, function(d) {
        return d.enrols;
    })]);

    bars.data(subset, function(d) {
        return d.month;
    });

    rects.transition().duration(500).attr("width", function(d) {
        return width - x(this.parentNode.__data__.enrols);
    });

    texts.transition().duration(500).attr("x", function(d) {
            return width - x(this.parentNode.__data__.enrols) - 15;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return this.parentNode.__data__.enrols;
        });

}
```

Here is your CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqBzWQ?editors=0010

PS: This would be even easier if you get rid of those groups, appending the rectangles and the texts directly.

Comment: `this.parentNode.__data__.enrols`? not `d.enrols`?

Comment: No, not `d`, unless we create an "enter", "update" and "exit" selection here, which is exactly what I am avoiding.

Comment: Thanks. This is a learning exercise for me - so what if the length of the data did change, i.e. I did not have data for November and December in the second subset of data?

Comment: In that scenario you'd need an "enter", "update" and "exit" selections (which are easier without groups, btw).